# Making a UIImageView stop moving when collision is detected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, collision-detection

I have a turret and a bullet, hooked up to properties of weak and nonamatic. I also have I large horizontal line leading down the View Controller.

Is there any way for a single button press to make the turret "shoot" the bullet, having the bullet's y position continuously increase? But here's the catch, it must stop immediately after colliding with the line.

NOTE: I've tried `[UIView animateWithDuration]` but the collision is always detected before the collision takes place.

Comment: Use UIDynamics. It's quite simple. All u have to define is one attachment, push and probably collision behaviours. Then u'll get more realistic feeling;)

Comment: @deathhorse On the Apple Developer website, they're quite vague about the UIPushBehaviour Class reference. Do you mind answering the question explaining how to use the pushDirection property as well as the magnitude property?

Answer (score 0):

In an app I created, to detect collisions I used something like this:

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(bullet.frame, line.frame)) {
    [self GameOver];
}
```

saying that if the bullet comes into contact with any part of the line, it will call on a method to end the game.

Comment: Already tried that. I think the [UIView animatewithDuration] makes it so the collision is detected early. I want a different way to move the image, and when the image collides it stops moving.